# TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.datetime in tweepy

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, tweepy, strptime, strftime

TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.datetime.
I want to fetch datetime format like below in my above code:

at the place of  `tweet.created_at

```
    outtweets = [[
    tweet.id_str,
    tweet.created_at.datetime.strptime(tweet.created_at.time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')  //please expected output format below
    tweet.favorite_count,
    tweet.retweet_count,
    ]
    for idx, tweet in enumerate(all_tweets)]


    df = DataFrame(outtweets,columns=["id",
                                      "created_at",
                                      "favorite_count",
                                      "retweet_count",
                                      ])
    print(df.head(10))
```

Comment: i want datetime format output = 2021-04-15T18:13:09Z likes this  where i have written this in loop tweet.created_at !

Comment: tweet.created_at should be a datetime object already, so if you want to format to string, `datetime.strftime(tweet.created_at, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tweet.created_at should be a datetime object already, so if you want to format to string, datetime.strftime(tweet.created_at, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')